# Can't deal with KDE Desktop in Kali Linux

Tags: debian, kali-linux, desktop, kde5

I recently installed KDE on Kali Linux (I'm always root). I can't do anything with the Desktop (Launching applications, creating or adding new items or moving icons to my secondary monitor, etc.).

I'm getting this error (eg. creating a Text File):

```
Unable to create io-slave. klauncher said: Error loading '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/kf5/kio/desktop.so'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a installation inconsistency (typical of kali)

Consulting https://debian.packages.org, it can be found out that path/file is supplied by the package `plasma-workspace` (list of files [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/plasma-workspace/filelist))

For installing it:

```
sudo apt install plasma-workspace
```

or if installed, for reinstalling it, to try to fix it, as:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install plasma-workspace
```

I would also advise reading my related answer [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/424740#424740)

PS. it was not lost on me the OP said "always root", `sudo` used for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Regarding the use of root, [see the relevant Kali documentation](https://docs.kali.org/policy/kali-linux-root-user-policy).

Comment: @StephenKitt I have done performance and security testing for top tier companies in the past, and still use network/security  tools once in a while. While those tools need often root privilege, we both  know that recommendation to run all the time as root is very misguided

Comment: I think it’s perfectly appropriate in the Kali context: a throwaway setup (on the live images at least) that’s only used for penetration and security testing and such like. I don’t think running as non-root in a Kali environment (when used as designed) would bring any significant benefit. I agree it’s at odds with best practice elsewhere, but then Kali isn’t a general-purpose Linux distribution.

Comment: @StephenKitt if someone is using all the time it v does not seem a throwaway setup. I am actually more concerned about the bad habits such recommendation creates